# PHP Redirect to page after submit

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a PHP contact form e-mail script so that after the submission, it redirects the user to a new page.  Currently, it sends the email, and outputs this at the bottom of the page: [""]

I tried adding this at the bottom, but it gave me an error:

```
header("Location: page2.php");
```

The PHP I'm using looks like this:

```
<?php

function send_json( $success = true, $data = '') {
    $response = array('');
    if ( ! empty($data)) {
        $response['data'] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    die;
}

function validate($name, $email) {
    $errors = array();
    if (null == $name) {
        $errors['name'] = 'Enter your name';
    }
    if (null == $email || false === $email) {
        $errors['email'] = 'Enter correct email';
    }
    // If errors - die
    if ( ! empty($errors)) {
        send_json(false, $errors);
    }
}

if (empty($_POST)) {
    exit;
}

// Load Config file
$ini = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.ini';
$config = parse_ini_file( $ini );

// Receive and validate data
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$company = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'company', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$referral = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'referral', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
// Do validate
validate($name, $email);

// If validate success
$body = " From: $name\n\n E-Mail: $email\n\n Address: $company\n\n Phone: $phone\n\n Referral: $referral\n\n";

// Send email
$to = $config['to'];
$subject = $config['subject'];

// From and Reply-To are the same
$from = sprintf( '%1$s <%2$s>', $name, $email);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = sprintf('From: %s', $from);
$headers[] = sprintf('Reply-To: %s', $from);
$headers[] = sprintf('X-Mailer: PHP/%s', phpversion());
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';

// Convert headers from array to string
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
send_json(); ?>
```

This .js is also part of the mailer:

```
(function () {
    /**
     * Element, where ajax response will be printed.
     * @type {*|jQuery|HTMLElement}
     */
    var responseHolder = $('.response-holder');
    function mailer_response_success(data) {
        var data = data || 'You have submitted an estimate for review. Thank you!';
        responseHolder.addClass('success').html('<div class="inner">' + data + '</div>');
    }

    function mailer_response_error(data) {
        var message = ('string' == typeof data) ? data : 'Sorry, AJAX error occurred';
        // If data not a scalar sting
        if ('object' == typeof data) {
            var a = [];

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                a.push(value);
            });
            message = a.join('<br>');
        }

        responseHolder.addClass('error').html('<div class="inner">' + message + '</div>');
    }

    // Mailer form handler
    $(document).on('submit', '#ajax-form', function (e) {
        // Stop form submitting
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $( this),
            formdata = form.serializeArray();

        responseHolder.html('');
        responseHolder.removeClass('success error');

        // Data validation here?
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mailer/mailer.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formdata,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(['kennedy.mailer.error', status, error, xhr.responseText]);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.success.length !== 0 && true == response.success) {
                    mailer_response_success();
                } else {
                    mailer_response_error(response.data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: This makes sense. You have an empty json string being output and you have no redirect code which wouldn't work anyway since you have output. You can redirect or have output, but not both.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Which should I use, and what should I remove?

Comment: Why do you need this send_json(); at the end after your mail() function ? Could you try removing this and add the redirection code right after the mail() function and see if that works?

Comment: Replace `send_json();` with `header("Location: page2.php"); exit;`

Comment: @Maximus2012 I tried that, but continually get this error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/65/7264665/html/verde/earlybird/index.php:9) in /home/content/65/7264665/html/verde/earlybird/mailer/mailer.php on line 75

Comment: Is this all the code that you have or is there more to it ?

Comment: @JohnConde Same error.  I had tried that, and I keep getting an error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

Comment: Something else not show here is causing you to have output. You need to hunt it down.\

Comment: That is because you're code is possibly trying to output some html code before you call the header function. It could be this function validate($name, $email). can you try commenting out this line and see if it works ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 I commented that out. It still sends, but I'm getting this output error again.  I edited my OP and included the .js that the mailer uses. I really did not think that could be affecting the redirect so I didn't include it.

Comment: It is possible that the js code might be causing this issue but it is hard to tell from your code since its not clear how the js/php code is interacting with each other. You might need to simplify your code a bit until you are able to find the part that is causing this issue.

Comment: @JohnConde I added the .js to the OP but I just can't seem to figure out how that could affect the redirect output

Comment: Get rid of the closing `?>` and see if that helps